# Define cardinality using interface

Tags: uml, cardinality

I'm getting a problem in UML, I have a class that must to have three another classes, that's okay, but when i try to put an interface between this connection I stuck, is there some good way to make a cardinality `1 to 3`?

That is my class diagram actually.

[image: My UML diagram class]

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to say is "An evaluation is linked to 3 any features" your model is correct. But if what you want to say is "An evaluation is linked to a consumption, a punctuality and a Trustworthiness. And each of theses is a feature". The correct model is something like this:

[image]

You can make a copy of this model [here](http://app.genmymodel.com/genmymodel?clonedProject=_qJ2ZEPqAEDCJJ7PnSCA59A)